# How can I get the default HeaderTitle which was set in Main tab Navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-drawer

I want to get the default HeaderTitle and update it as per my component.
Header Title is added in MainTabNavigator as

```
const navOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: (
      <Image source={require("../assets/images/common/logo.png")}/>
    ),
  };
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Dashboard
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions: navOptions
  },
);
```

I want to toggle between headerTitle on some events please suggest me the solution as I want to keep the headerTitle only on one location and toggle between it as per required.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: QueryTocheck ? keepDefaultOldHeaderHere:updateHeaderHere
});
```

Comment: You want to set a header title for each screen?

Comment: I want to change header title on some event and also want to keep the old header which was passed by the navigator.